# lsp-mode can't register custom lsp client using with-eval-after-load

Tags: spacemacs, lsp-mode, lsp

I am trying to use a custom lsp server.  I place the following snippet in my init file:

```
  (with-eval-after-load 'lsp-mode
    (add-to-list 'lsp-language-id-configuration '(solidity-mode . "soldity"))
    (add-to-list 'lsp-language-id-configuration '("\\.sol$" . "solidity"))
    (lsp-register-client
     (make-lsp-client :new-connection (lsp-stdio-connection '("solidity-ls" "--stdio"))
                      :activation-fn (lsp-activate-on "solidity")
                      :server-id 'solidity)))
```

But when I open a .sol file no lsp mode is activated. If I manually use `M-x lsp` I get a message saying that semgrep lsp is available but not installed, and the `lsp-log` has this message: `Command "semgrep lsp" is not present on the path.`

I don't want semgrep lsp. I want my custom solidity lsp client.  `M-x describe-variable` for `lsp-language-id-configuration` shows that my `add-to-list` statements have had zero effect. `M-x describe-mode` shows that I'm in `solidity/*l` mode. The only way I can get my custom lsp client to work is by navigating to my init file, selecting the following region, and using `M-x eval-region`

```
    (add-to-list 'lsp-language-id-configuration '(solidity-mode . "soldity"))
    (add-to-list 'lsp-language-id-configuration '("\\.sol$" . "solidity"))
    (lsp-register-client
     (make-lsp-client :new-connection (lsp-stdio-connection '("solidity-ls" "--stdio"))
                      :activation-fn (lsp-activate-on "solidity")
                      :server-id 'solidity))
```

How can I get lsp-mode to register my lsp-client automatically when I open a .sol file?

NB: I'm using spacemacs and the following instructions for adding a custom lsp server https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/adding-new-language/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the logic to a `solidity-mode-hook` and requiring `lsp-mode` inside the hook fixed things. I also added a notification handler to ignore an event that `lsp-mode` doesn't recognize and hence causes errors.

```
  (add-hook 'solidity-mode-hook
            (lambda ()
              (require 'lsp-mode)
              (add-to-list 'lsp-language-id-configuration '(solidity-mode . "soldity"))
              (add-to-list 'lsp-language-id-configuration '("\\.sol$" . "solidity"))
              (lsp-register-client
               (make-lsp-client :new-connection (lsp-stdio-connection '("solidity-ls" "--stdio"))
                                :activation-fn (lsp-activate-on "solidity")
                                :notification-handlers
                                (ht ("textDocument/didOpen" #'ignore))
                                :server-id 'solidity))
              (lsp)
              )
            )
```

EDIT: I had to enclose the code inside the hook in a lambda.